# Bootstrap 4 table doesn't occupy full horizontal space in tab-content div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'd like my bootstrap table to fill all the available horizontal space.

When I take the demo tables from the [table docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/) (which *do* fill all the vertical space on the bootstrap docs page), they don't fill all the horizontal space on my site. The only thing I can think of is that my table is inside a `tab-content` div -- would that make a difference?

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
            <table class="table table-responsive">
                ...
```

I've also tried:

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <table class="table table-responsive">
                    ...
```

,

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <table class="table table-responsive">
                        ...
```

But these seem desperate and don't work. What am I missing? **How do I make my tables responsive, filling whatever horizontal space is available in the column div?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is because of the `tab-content` div.  You have two options, either remove it or add css to that div to have the same width style as a table.  All you need to do is either add a new class or apply different css to that class.  I would suggest adding a class in case you have other references of `tab-content` on that page.  Something like:

```
.tab-contentOverride {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

And check out my codepen for the differences:

https://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/BwYJYa